# Which accented characters are considered the same?

Tags: mysql, character-set, utf-8

In MySQL, certain characters are considered the same when performing searches, e.g. 'n' and 'ñ'; unless you specify BINARY in the condition.

Is there a list somewhere of the characters that are considered the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case or accent sensitivity behavior is defined by the collation you are using.

The full list of comparable characters in a given collation can be found in [collationcharts](http://collation-charts.org/) where you find the [MySQL list of collations](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/)

If you find your collation in that list you will see a chart of comparable characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a summary of the utf8 collations: http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

It shows that 'n' and 'ñ' are considered equal for all but `utf8_bin`, `utf8_spanish2_ci`, and `utf8_spanish_ci`  In the Spanish cases, `Ñ` and `ñ` are treated like a separate letter and sort after `nz` and before `o`.

(Latvian and Polish have a couple of flavors of `n` that work like the Spanish `ñ`; but perhaps that is in of importance to you.)

Comment: Oh... I did not check to see whether "combining tilde" (hex CC83) plus "n" is equal.  I'm pretty sure it is for utf8_unicode_ci but not utf8_general_ci; don't know about utf8_spanish*.

Comment: I got frustrated trying to understand /mysql60/, so I wrote code to generate my page.